# How do I get Apache Kafka to connect to salesforce via Apache Camel connector?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, salesforce, apache-kafka-connect

I have downloaded the `camel-salesforce-kafka-connector` from
https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/0.11.0/reference/index.html

I have a kafka instance running locally along with `connector-distributed` running as well.

If I attempt to configure the connector using the connector class as specified in the documentation https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/connectors/camel-salesforce-source-kafka-source-connector.html

(sample query)

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8083/connectors \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "name": "CamelSalesforceSinkConnector",
        "config": {
          "connector.class":"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforcesource.CamelSalesforcesourceSourceConnector",
          "camel.component.salesforce.loginUrl":"https://[my instance].my.salesforce.com/",
          "camel.component.salesforce.authenticationType":"USERNAME_PASSWORD",
          "camel.component.salesforce.userName":"[username]",
          "camel.component.salesforce.password":"[password][token]",
          "camel.component.salesforce.clientId":"[redacted]",
          "camel.source.path.topicName":"MyTopicName",
          "camel.component.salesforce.notifyForOperations":"ALL",
          "camel.component.salesforce.sObjectName": "MyCustomObject__c"
        }
    }'
```

I get the error set:

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforcesource.CamelSalesforcesourceSourceConnector, available connectors are: 
// [** skipped content **]
PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector, name='org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector', version='0.11.0', encodedVersion=0.11.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/alexchesser/www/kafka-salesforce-connect/camel-salesforce-kafka-connector-0.11.0-package/camel-salesforce-kafka-connector/camel-kafka-connector-0.11.0.jar'},
// [** skipped content **]
```

If I instead re-run the same query as above with `org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector` in the place of `connector.class` I get

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Request failed.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500 Request failed.</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/connectors</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Request failed.</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-36c281ed</td></tr>
</table>
<hr><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.43.v20210629</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

which in the logs for the connector server shows up as

```
[2021-12-17 14:11:19,970] WARN /connectors (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel:677)
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:410)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:438)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector.config(CamelSourceConnector.java:67)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:450)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:362)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        ... 1 more
[2021-12-17 14:11:19,974] WARN unhandled due to prior sendError (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState:787)
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:410)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:438)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector.config(CamelSourceConnector.java:67)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:450)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:362)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        ... 1 more
```

When setting up a `camel-kafka-to-salesforce-connector` what steps am I potentially missing?

**edit** OK pushing a little harder on this, it looks like the

`"connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforce.CamelSalesforceSourceConnector",`

is indeed the right connector to call, but for some reason downloading the package and placing it in the plugins path doesn't automatically register it with Kafka Connect.

I think the solution is to figure out how to make sure the package gets recognized by connect

Comment: So, you've downloaded a JAR? And placed it where? Did you modify your `plugin.path` in `connect-distributed.properties`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the question. So the downloaded JAR has been unzipped to a folder and plugin.path has been modified to include that folder.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - turns out you were right about folder path stuff. I had the system set up with a very long pathname in my home directory. When I instead extracted to and used `/usr/share/java` it did work as expected. I must have had a typo or was pointing at an incorrect folder.